# Need help using explode, preg_match

Tags: php, regex, explode, preg-split

I have over one thousand reviews in a string. I have been asked to see if i can get the average rate from each author. an example of the string is below. I have highlighted the content which I need to extract into an array.

> Shepherd's Bush Empire (Times p54 - **4* David Sinclair**)Grizzly Bear - Serpentine Sessions, Hyde Park, London (Independent Viewspaper p17 - **4* Elisa Bray**)Blondie – Kenwood House (Sun p69 – **4* JJ**)Jeff Tweedy - Union Chapel, London (Independent Viewspaper p17 - **4* Enjoli Liston**)Tony Bennett - Albert Hall, London (Times p68 - **4* Clive Davis**, Standard p40 – **5* Jack Massarick**

Is there anyway to explode the string on `*` go back one character and forward to words.

I know there will be odds but these can be removed later. is there a way of using `preg_split` or `explode`?

Comment: I expect http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php would be the base of your solution, but my regex foo is sadly lacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find a single number followed by an asterisk, then two words separated by a space

```
preg_match_all("/\d\* ?\w* ?\w*/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

and here's an example link http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/7Ty

your output array will look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4* David Sinclair
            [1] => 4* Elisa Bray
            [2] => 4* JJ
            [3] => 4* Enjoli Liston
            [4] => 4* Clive Davis
            [5] => 5* Jack Massarick
        )

)
```

EDIT::
for adding an optional decimal place use this `/\d(\.\d{1,2})?\* ?\w* ?\w*/`

Comment: brilliant thank you, great link as well i will be saving that tool

Comment: just noticed there are a couple of 3.5* is there any way to include these?

Comment: I updated my answer to show the regex with adding an optional 1 or 2 digit decimal place. @gareth

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex something like:

```
([0-9]+) *\* *([^\)]+)
```

Should do the trick.

This looks for 1 or more digits, (saving them), followed by zero or more discarded spaces, a literal `*`, followed by any number of discarded spaces, followed by any number of any characters but literal `)`, saving them.